# Why myLocation becomes null when onSuccess() gets terminated even when myLocation is a global variable?

Tags: java, android, location

myLocation value becomes null when the method onSuccess() is terminated. I am new to android app development. I want to store the currentlocation's value in myLocation permanently.

I am following google's Developers Guide to get my currentlocation and i want to store it to myLocation (Global variable). I have successfully obtained my currentlocation but it is not getting stored in myLocation permanently. After onSuccess() method the myLocation becomes null.

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

```
private GoogleMap mMap;
private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;
SupportMapFragment mapFragment;
Location myLocation;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    myLocation = new Location(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
     mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);

    mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ) {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
    }
    else{
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    }
}



@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ) {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
    }

    mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
            .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Location currentlocation) {
                    myLocation=currentlocation;
                    // Got last known location. In some rare situations this can be null.
                    if (currentlocation != null) {

                        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(myLocation.getLatitude(), myLocation.getLongitude());
                        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("My Location"));
                        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));


                    }
                }
            });
    Log.i("myLocation",myLocation.toString());


}
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please provide permission", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }


}
```

}

myLocation should be equal to currentlocation but it is found to be null in Logs..
Logs - I/myLocation: Location[network 0.000000,0.000000 acc=??? t=?!? et=?!?]
Please help me and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Log get called before your `onSuccess()`, because it's a `Listener`. What you should do is put the call for

```
Log.i("myLocation",myLocation.toString());
```

in your `onSuccess()`, after that you have the right value.

Comment: thanks. But why it has given preference to Log over Listener in onMapReady() ?

Comment: It's because the Listener is asynchronous, so you make a call and wait it's response. However the code keeps running and the Log gets called before you receive the result.